# Updating JDK in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been having problems with appcompat_v7, someone told me to use Android-21 target.  An error with that got me told to use JDK 1.8.  I currently have JDK 1.6 installed.  How do I switch Eclipse over to use JDK 1.8?  I see no place to set the JDK path.   The other time this question was asked, the questioner was referred to the JRE settings ... but the JDK is not the JRE, there are two separate paths.  How do I get Eclipse to use the new JDK?

Comment: Just set the path to the "Installed JRE" to the JDK e.g, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`. Eclipse calls it an "Installed JRE" even if it's a JDK.

Answer (score 1):

```
Project Menu > Properties menu item > Java Compiler > Compiler Compliance Level
```

Select your Java version from the pulldown menu. Obviously, you'll need to install Java 1.8 first to get it to show up as an installed version.

Comment: I have installed 1.8 ... but the compliance levels only go to 1.7.  I still need to somehow tell Eclipse about the 1.8 path.  How ?